# PHP: "-" turns to "0"

Tags: php, forms

This is the form I have:

```
<form action="data.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
    <input type="text" name="num2"><br>
    <input type="submit" >
</form>
```

when I

```
echo $_GET['num1'] . + "-" . + $_GET['num2'];
```

it gets like:

```
505
```

while I want:

```
5-5
```

Why does my `-` turning to `0`?

Comment: Typecasting because of the unary `+`. Why did you try to double the concat `.` operator with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` is the [addition operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php), not the concatenation operator. [That's `.`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php). The `+` forces PHP to [type juggle](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) the dash into an integer so it can do the math you asked for and as a result the dash becomes zero.

You should remove them as you are already using the right operator:

```
echo $_GET['num1'] . + "-" . + $_GET['num2'];
```

should become

```
echo $_GET['num1'] . "-" . $_GET['num2'];
```

Comment: We've all done this at on epoint. Too much switching back and forth between java/JavaScript and PHP.

Comment: Yeah, I would agree there ;l-)

Comment: Works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `+` operator is used for addition. The `.` operator is for concatenation.

You can drop the `+` in your code, or you can just put everything together without using concatenation, like this:

```
echo "{$_GET['num1']}-{$_GET['num2']}";
```